# sql query for musique library

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, database

i'm still learning and i'm searching for some help cause i can't understand the logic and the strategy to create all tables that i need.

I got a table with all my musics.
the rows are : id, nbrEcoute, titre, artiste, album, style, année, imgPochette, adresseMusique.

I wanna create a table that contains all album, artistes and style in alphabetic order.

I know i need to "SELECT album FROM dbMusique" but i get 10 lines with the same album name. Which command should i use? If you could show me an example with album for example.

Thanks

```
id: 1
nbrEcoute: 0
titre: Up All Night
artiste: Owl City
album: Preview
style: NULL
année: 2012
imgPochette: http://i.imgur.com/nzRNHlx.jpg
adresseMusique: ---
```

Comment: do you have 10 duplicate entries? Try SELECT * FROM dbMusique. If you wish to order by add ORDER BY titre DESC or ORDER BY titre ASC

Comment: i just want to take tha album row, not all of them so I can't use  SELECT * FROM dbMusique.
I search a command like:  SELECT album FROM dbMusique WHERE AlbumIsNotTheSame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
SELECT album FROM dbMusique GROUP BY album ORDER BY album ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to query a table that you already created. To retrieve different albums you want to type the distinct function, assuming that an album only has one artist and one style.

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.album, M.artiste, M.style 
FROM dbMusique M
ORDER BY M.album, M.artiste, M.style;
```